# Customised Sequence Diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, diagrams

I want to draw this[image]

With the light gray shadow (not black) and round corners. Here is what I have

[image]

Can anyone show me how to change it? Another points, when I have text that is very long, how can I break it to many lines so they dont go out of the borders?

Here is my MWV

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shadows}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}

\begin{document}

\begin{sequencediagram}
\newthread[white]{u}{User}
\newinst[3]{b}{Browser}


\begin{call}{u}{Long messagessssssssssssssss here!!!}{b}{}
\end{call}

\end{sequencediagram}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
\tikzset{inststyle/.append style={
        drop shadow={top color=gray, bottom color=white}, 
        rounded corners=2.0ex
}
```

to change the style of the `\newinst`.  Here it is shown applied *only* to the `Browser`:

[image]

### Notes:

- I don't know the *official* `pgf-umlsd` way to wrap the text, but using a `\parbox` sure works.
- I added the `\tikzset` within a brace group so that any subsequent `\newinst` would not be affected as I thought perhaps you would want to change only one of the `\newinst`. If you desire *all* the `\newinst` to have the gray shadow box and `rounded corner` move the above `\tikzset` to be in the preamble *before* `\begin{document}`.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shadows}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}

\begin{document}

\begin{sequencediagram}
\newthread[white]{u}{User}

{\tikzset{inststyle/.append style={
        drop shadow={top color=gray, bottom color=white}, 
        rounded corners=2.0ex
    }
}
\newinst[3]{b}{Browser}%
}%

\begin{call}{u}{\parbox[b]{4.0cm}{\raggedright Long messagess sssss sssssssss here!!!}}{b}{}
\end{call}

\end{sequencediagram}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you happen how to reshape the boxes? To make them rounded corners?

Comment: @wererabit: Updated solution to include `rounded corners`.